# How to transpose a single row then export that to PDF from excel 2007 in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, transpose, updating, export-to-pdf

Im very very new to coding, especially in VBA, and Im having problems I hope someone can help me with. I've tried a few solutions online but I cant seem to get it working. Im also stuck in excel 2007 :/

I have a worksheet that has a userform I've built in VBA that will add some data to a bunch of columns. Ive also got some formulas that modify some of that data and produce a unique identifier to each one, this is important later.

Im trying to export each individual row (with the shared headers) into a PDF, and I figure transposing it to 2 columns would work much better. So far I can only export the whole worksheet and it comes out terrible with 88 pages of mostly nothing. The hard mode of this is that I also want it to be named the unique identifier and hyperlinked back into the spreadsheet under that cell..

I know im asking a lot but if anyone can send me in the right direction Id really appreciate it, even links to others. I dont know enough to even know what Im looking for. Any comments at all are appreciated.

My code so far, again, sorry for the mess;

Many thanks for **any help** at all!

```
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1


 With ws
 '  .Unprotect Password:="password"
.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")
.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.ComboBox7.Value
.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.TextBox12.Value
.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.TextBox11.Value
.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.CheckBox4.Value
.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.ListBox4.Value
 'Row 7 Reserved for Identifier Code!!
.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
.Cells(iRow, 9).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
.Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Me.ComboBox5.Value
.Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Me.ComboBox6.Value
.Cells(iRow, 12).Value = Me.TextBox7.Value
.Cells(iRow, 13).Value = Me.TextBox8.Value
.Cells(iRow, 14).Value = Me.TextBox13.Value
.Cells(iRow, 15).Value = Me.TextBox14.Value
.Cells(iRow, 16).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
.Cells(iRow, 17).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
.Cells(iRow, 18).Value = Me.TextBox9.Value
.Cells(iRow, 19).Value = Me.ComboBox4.Value
.Cells(iRow, 20).Value = Me.TextBox10.Value
.Cells(iRow, 21).Value = Me.TextBox15.Value
.Cells(iRow, 22).Value = Me.CheckBox5.Value
.Cells(iRow, 23).Value = Me.CheckBox6.Value
.Cells(iRow, 24).Value = Me.CheckBox7.Value
.Cells(iRow, 25).Value = Me.CheckBox8.Value
.Cells(iRow, 26).Value = Me.CheckBox9.Value

End With


'Export to PDF.. needs work...

Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:="C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Excel Testing\Export.pdf", _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be better to export a specific range.  `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:="C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Excel Testing\Export.pdf", _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False `

Comment: Thanks TinMan, it looks cleaner but I still have a 116 page PDF :/ I have 27 Columns so far and could be adding more later. Do you know if a way to transpose them before exporting? Again any help or comment is useful.

Answer (score 0):

This will transpose a header row and a row of data.

```
Sub ExportTransposedRow(Header As Range, Source As Range)

    With Worksheets.Add
        Header.Copy
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        Source.Copy
        .Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

        .UsedRange.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                       Filename:="C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Excel Testing\Export.pdf", _
                                       OpenAfterPublish:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

### Usage

> ```
> ExportTransposedRow Rows(1),Rows(3)
> ```

Comment: TinMan Thank you very much for this. I am unsure how to call on a new Sub though. How can I tie this into a button or macro to run each time?

Comment: I am not sure how you want to call the subroutine.  It will work as long as you pass it two valid ranges.  `ExportTransposedRow ws.Cells(1).Resize(1, 26),ws.Cells(iRow).Resize(1, 26)` will work for your sample code.

Comment: you are very good thanks. Where would I put that new line of code too?

I have tried 
    `Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
    Call ExportTransposedRow

    End Sub`

But I get a Compile error, "argument not optional

Comment: You should watch: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 18 - Creating Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bsfe-2VcvZg&index=20&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: Thanks TinMan!
Have to do some work now so gotta put projects on the side for a bit.
I will will watch it though and try to get it running, ill update on progress when I can. It started as a small project to try to automate some of my paperwork, but who knew how difficult coding could be :) Thanks again